# Python doesnt recognize the replace command

Tags: python

trying to build a very simple live clock, but for some reason Python doesn't recognize 'replace,' does anyone know how to fix this?

```
currenttime = now = datetime.now().time()
txt = print(now)

while True:
  x = txt.replace(now, now)
  print(x)
```

Comment: Please explain your end result. How do you want it to look like? Right now, replacing something with same thing does not make sense. Also, if you print `txt`, you will see a `None`, because `print` returns a `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` function does not return a string. Try to replace it with this:

```
# txt = print(now)  # change this
txt = str(now)
```

EDIT: Your code is also incorrect, you are replacing now with same now. Just do this:

```
while True:
  print(datetime.now().time())
```

Comment: It looks to me OP is trying to replace something, not just printing. Why do you suggest to just print `datetime.now().time()`? OP does not show his expected output.

Comment: Because OP is just trying to build a simple clock :) But still it does not make sense to replace a string with the same string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the code. Do it in a simpler way. Try this out. I am adding sleep so that you can see it smoothly. Remove sleep after getting satisfied by the code. it will update after every 500ms

```
import time


while True:
  currenttime = now = datetime.now().time()
  txt = str(now)
  x = txt.replace(now, txt)
  print(x)
  time.sleep(0.5)
```